# Insert and return ID of sub-document in MongoDB document sub-document array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My node.js application will insert a sub-document into a nested sub-document array field of the following MongoDB document, and I need to determine the ID of the newly inserted sub-document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("578d5a52cc13117022e09def"),
  "name" : "Grade 5 - Section A",
  "scores" : [{
    "studentId" : ObjectId("5776bd36ffc8227405d364d2"),
    "performance" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("57969b8fc164a21c20698261"),
      "subjectId" : ObjectId("577694ecbf6f3a781759c54a"),
      "score" : 86,
      "maximum" : 100,
      "grade" : "B+"
    }]
  }]
}
```

The sub-document looks like this:

```
{
  "subjectId" : ObjectId("5776ffe1804540e29c602a62"),
  "score" : 74,
  "maximum" : 100,
  "grade" : "A-"
}
```

I am adding the sub-document using the following Mongoose code:

```
Class.update({
  _id: '578d5a52cc13117022e09def',
  'scores.studentId': '5776bd36ffc8227405d364d2'
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'scores.$.performance': {
      'subjectId' : '5776ffe1804540e29c602a62',
      'score' : 74,
      'maximum' : 100,
      'grade' : 'A-'
    }
  }
}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

The *subject* sub-document gets added in the `performance` sub-document array which is itself nested in the `scores` sub-document array. Notice that the newly inserted sub-document is assigned with its own ID, as instituted by the defined schema. Even if I get back the entire document, that's not very helpful. I specifically need the ID of that newly inserted sub-document. What is the recommended approach to this problem?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760087/find-id-of-latest-subdocument-inserted-in-mongoose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I prefer pre-assign the ID to the sub-document (i.e. `sub._id = ObjectId()` or use `uuid` package if you prefer uuid): is clear and predictable.

Also remember that if you frequent query by a subdoc id is good to add (using `ensureIndex()`) an index for this use case in the collection.

Comment: @Dano, I ended up adding `'_id' : new ObjectID(),` to the sub-document to be inserted, so MongoDB used that. I appreciate the heads up on the index. Yes, I will be querying frequently, so I will add an index in the collection.

Comment: Is there any way to make `'_id' : new ObjectID(),` work in mongo Shell ?

Comment: so if you explicitly assign object _id to a sub-document, this _id WILL NOT be automatically indexed, and query will be slow, right?

Comment: of course, no! indexing doesn't depend if the value is autogenerated or not. you can use ObjectIDs, UUID, ULID, integer or whatever you want. But you will need to `ensureIndex` on it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good solution for that, try to use the methods `create` and `push` of the MongooseArrays.

In your code you could return the `Student` and do something like this:

```
const newPerformance = student.performance.create(newData);
student.performance.push(newPerformance);
const updatedStudent = await student.save();

if (updatedStudent) return newPerformance._id;
```

This is just a simple example.

Using the `create` method of MongooseArrays, [link for doc](https://github.com/matheusrocha89.private.atom?token=ADi83krSvdF2-o8ALecmu4-DeQS80od1ks62F124wA==), the mongoose will create an `_id` and do all the validations and casts it needs, so if the save process is fine the created subdocument you could just use the `_id` of the subdocument you got with the `create` method.

Comment: I am not familiar with MongooseArrays. Is this a separate library I need to require into the project? I notice this use of ES6 constructs with const and await. That is part of generator functions, if I recall correctly from past reading.

Comment: This is part of mongoose, see on the docs link i put. I just used es6 to be easier to understand the example, it's not an obligation.

Comment: You're welcome. Today I am working on a project and I am using mongoose, I passed through this same situation a couple of days ago.

Comment: This is the most correct answer for latest mongoose versions.

Comment: Any one, I think the questions try to indicate about the deeply nested sub documents.