# retrieve ._id of sub-document in array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to get the objectid of the newly created member, by doing this:

```
let member = await account.members.push(body);  
let acct = await account.save();
console.log(member); //result is an integer
let team_member_id = acct.members[member].id;
```

I get an error: **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: after a bit of searching it looks like the recommended approach is to pre-assign a new ObjectID() , so that I dont have to look it up - Is this still the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
let member = account.members.create(body);
account.members.push(member);  
const acct = await account.save();  
         
let team_member_id = member.id;
```

[Insert and return ID of sub-document in MongoDB document sub-document array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597545/insert-and-return-id-of-sub-document-in-mongodb-document-sub-document-array)

Comment: If this fixed your issue, please mark your own answer as accepted, thanks.

Comment: I dont have enough rep at the moment.  Which is a shame cause I would love to upvote hundreds of solutions that have helped me.

Comment: Hm, I thought that you can always accept your own answer (not upvote) regardless of your reputation. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: There is a 48 hour waiting period, fyi