# Insert into embedded document and return inserted sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with embedded document as below.

```
const ParentSchema = new Schema({
    field: String,
    items: [
        {
            field: String,
            field2: Number,
            field3: Number
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to insert a sub document (into items field) and get the last inserted sub document. (Because I need the objectId of that sub socument).

I can implement it as below.

```
Parent.updateOne(
        { _id: parentId },
        {
            $push: {
                items: {
                    field: String,
                    field2: Number,
                    field3: Number
                }
            }
        }
)
```

But this will return a result object not last inserted sub document. For that I may use another query to get last embedded document. I want a optimal solution for this.

Comment: you can use `{ new: true }` property in options, but this will return the whole document, not just inserted sub-document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert and return ID of sub-document in MongoDB document sub-document array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597545/insert-and-return-id-of-sub-document-in-mongodb-document-sub-document-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate` with option `new: true` to get the updated document then do something like `doc.items[doc.items.length - 1]` to get the inserted sub document without using another query:

```
let doc = await Parent.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: parentId },
    {
        $push: {
            items: {
                field: field,
                field2: field2,
                field3: field3
            }
        }
    }, 
    { new: true }
);
console.log(doc.items[doc.items.length - 1]);
```